# Put a value in webkit console from console.log into a variable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit, web-inspector

If there is an output in the chrome/safari webkit inspector containing an object that prints out such as:

[image]

Only much more complicated with loads of nested objects (which is why a copy/paste wont do)

Is there a way to put this in a variable to inspect in further and process it after its been printed on the console (its printed via `console.log`), just only after its already in the console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to do it *without* wrapping `console.log` in a custom log function:

```
var justLogged;
var oldLog = console.log;

console.log = function () {
    oldLog.apply(console, arguments);
    justLogged = arguments;
};

console.log('test');

// if necessary, restore console.log to its original behavior when you're finished with it
console.log = oldLog;
```

The value of `justLogged` will be `['test']`, since you just logged it.

Comment: It's better to do `oldLog.apply(this, arguments)` to pass all arguments instead of just the first one.

Comment: @Mohsen good point, I updated the code to use `apply` instead of `call`.

Answer (score 6):

`$_` will give you last output of console. So in console you can assign in to a variable.

[image]

Note that you can do this only in console and not from your own code.

Comment: I didn't even know that! Thats a really awesome tip!

Comment: Never knew that was possible. I wonder if you could listen to console events as well?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to get the last *output*, [do as Mohsen suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464757/put-a-value-in-webkit-console-from-console-log-into-a-variable/15464845#15464845).

If you're trying to get the last output of `console.log`, your best bet is a wrapper function. This can (1) do what you want (2) easily be disabled in production, which is helpful on old IE and hides debug messages.

```
var log = (function() {
    var lastOutput;
    var fn = function() {
        lastOutput = arguments[0];              // save the last argument
        console.log.apply(console, arguments);  // defer to console.log
    };
    fn.last = function() {
        return lastOutput;
    };
    return fn;
})();

log("abc123");
log.last();     // => "abc123"
```